# WordPress 'circular' pagination within category for custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, pagination

I'm trying to build a post slider in WordPress, showing custom posts from a specific category, and adding pagination on the posts. I want this pagination to be circular, so that the last post links to the first post and vice versa.

It's almost working perfectly, but for some reason the most recent post 'previous' link is linking to itself rather than the previous post (the 'next' link is correctly going to the oldest post in that category) and I'm stumped as to why.

If I just use

```
<?php next_post_link('%link', '%title', TRUE); ?>
<?php previous_post_link('%link', '%title', TRUE); ?>
```

it works correctly but without being circular. But if I add in the If statements to show the first/last links if there isn't a next/prev item, the most recent post stops thinking it's got a previous post to link to even though it has.

This is my full code:

```
<?php $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'pub',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => 99,
            'category__in' => 17,
            'order' => 'DESC',
        );
        $arr_posts = new WP_Query( $args ); 
            $post = $posts[0]; $c=0;  ?>
                    <?php 
                 if ( $arr_posts->have_posts() ) : 
        ?>
<section class="above-fold-splash">
<div class="mySlider">
    <?php
while ( $arr_posts->have_posts() ) : 
    $arr_posts->the_post();
    $image = get_field('photo');
    $image_size_big = 'full';
$image_size_small = 'large-square';
$image_array_big = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image, $image_size_big);
$image_array_small = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image, $image_size_small);
$image_url = $image_array_big[0];
$image_url_small = $image_array_small[0];
    $logo = get_field('logo');
    if( $logo ):
            
        // Image variables.
        $logourl = $logo['url'];
        $logotitle = $logo['title'];
        $logoalt = $logo['alt'];

    endif;
    $website = get_field('website_address');
    ?>
    <div class="slide">
<div class="background-image desktop" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $image_url; ?>);"></div>
<div class="background-image mobile" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $image_url_small; ?>);"></div>
<div class="overlay"></div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col full">
        <div class="image" data-aos="fade" data-aos-offset="0" data-aos-duration="2000" data-aos-delay="1000"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $logo ); ?></div>
        <div data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-offset="0" data-aos-duration="2000" data-aos-delay="1000" class="buttons">
        <a class="button icon-none left" href="<?php echo $website; ?>"><span class="icon left"><span class="nothover"></span><span class="hover"></span></span><span class="text">Visit Website</span><span class="icon right"><span class="nothover"></span><span class="hover"></span></span></a>
        <a class="button icon-none right" href="/our-pubs"><span class="icon left"><span class="nothover"></span><span class="hover"></span></span><span class="text">See All Pubs</span><span class="icon right"><span class="nothover"></span><span class="hover"></span></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slider-pagination">
    <?php
$next_post = get_next_post(true);
if ( ! empty( $next_post ) ): ?>
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $next_post->ID ); ?>">
    <?php echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $next_post->post_title ); ?>
</a>
<?php else: 
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'pub',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'category__in' => 17,
    'order' => 'ASC',
 );
        $last = new WP_Query($args); $last->the_post();
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';
        wp_reset_postdata();
 endif; 
$prev_post = get_previous_post(true);
if ( ! empty( $prev_post ) ): ?>
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $prev_post->ID ); ?>">
    <?php echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $prev_post->post_title ); ?>
</a>
<?php else:    
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'pub',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'category__in' => 17,
    'order' => 'DESC',
 );
$first = new WP_Query($args); $first->the_post();
echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';
wp_reset_postdata();
 endif; ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; else : endif;  ?>
</div>
</section>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really interesting question.

As per your comments. In a `single.php`/`singular.php` context.

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) :
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

  the_title( '<h1>', '</h1>' );
  the_content();

endwhile;

  if( ! empty( get_previous_post() ) ):
    echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink( get_previous_post()->ID ) . '"> << </a>';
  else:
    echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink( get_posts ("post_type=" . get_query_var( 'post_type' ) . "&numberposts=1&order=DESC")[0]->ID ) . '"> << </a>';
  endif;
  if( ! empty( get_next_post() ) ):
    echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink( get_next_post()->ID ) . '"> >> </a>';
  else:
    echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink( get_posts( "post_type=" . get_query_var( 'post_type' ) . "&numberposts=1&order=ASC")[0]->ID ) . '"> >> </a>';
  endif;

endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hiya, Thanks for this but I think we're talking at cross purposes - it looks like the code you've written is for pagination between pages of posts, right? Whereas I'm talking about pagination on individual posts themselves - next_post_link() rather than next_posts_link(). Unless I've misunderstood your comment?

Comment: That's the same you can just adapt it.

Comment: But it's not linking to the post itself, is it? It looks like it's linking to the first page (or last page) of search results for that post type - I'm trying to get the link (and title) of the actual post.

Comment: Ok, got what you meant. I've added an edit to the answer.

Comment: Ah amazing, thanks, this got me where I need to be! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code by amarinediary I made some slight changes to include the category filter and got it working! Full code below:

```
<?php           $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'pub',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => 99,
            'category__in' => 17,
            'order' => 'DESC',          
        );
        $arr_posts = new WP_Query( $args ); 
            $post = $posts[0]; $c=0;  ?>
                    <?php 
                 if ( $arr_posts->have_posts() ) : 
        ?>

<section class="above-fold-splash">
    <div class="mySlider">
        <?php
        while ( $arr_posts->have_posts() ) : 
            $arr_posts->the_post();
            $image = get_field('photo');
            $image_size_big = 'full';
            $image_size_small = 'large-square';
            $image_array_big = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image, $image_size_big);
            $image_array_small = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image, $image_size_small);
            $image_url = $image_array_big[0];
            $image_url_small = $image_array_small[0];
            $logo = get_field('logo');
                if( $logo ):
                        
                    // Image variables.
                    $logourl = $logo['url'];
                    $logotitle = $logo['title'];
                    $logoalt = $logo['alt'];

                endif;
            $website = get_field('website_address');
        ?>
<div class="slide">
<div class="background-image desktop" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $image_url; ?>);"></div>
<div class="background-image mobile" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $image_url_small; ?>);"></div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col full">
        <div class="image" data-aos="fade" data-aos-offset="0" data-aos-duration="2000" data-aos-delay="1000"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $logo ); ?></div>
        <div data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-offset="0" data-aos-duration="2000" data-aos-delay="1000" class="buttons">
        <a class="button icon-none left" href="<?php echo $website; ?>"><span class="icon left"><span class="nothover"></span><span class="hover"></span></span><span class="text">Visit Website</span><span class="icon right"><span class="nothover"></span><span class="hover"></span></span></a>
        <a class="button icon-none right" href="/our-pubs"><span class="icon left"><span class="nothover"></span><span class="hover"></span></span><span class="text">See All Pubs</span><span class="icon right"><span class="nothover"></span><span class="hover"></span></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slider-pagination">
    <div class="prev">
        <?php if( ! empty( get_next_post(true) ) ):
        echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink( get_next_post(true)->ID ) . '">' . get_the_title( get_next_post(true)->ID ) . '</a>';
        else:
        echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink( get_posts( "post_type=pub&numberposts=1&order=ASC&cat=17")[0]->ID ) . '">' . get_the_title( get_posts( "post_type=pub&numberposts=1&order=ASC&cat=17")[0]->ID ) . '</a>';
        endif; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="next">
        <?php   if( ! empty( get_previous_post(true) ) ):
        echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink( get_previous_post(true)->ID ) . '">' . get_the_title( get_previous_post(true)->ID ) . '</a>';
        else:
        echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink( get_posts ("post_type=pub&numberposts=1&order=DESC&cat=17")[0]->ID ) . '">' . get_the_title( get_posts( "post_type=pub&numberposts=1&order=DESC&cat=17")[0]->ID ) . '</a>';
        endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div> <!-- end slide-->
</div> <!-- end MySlider-->
</section>
<?php  endif;  wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```